# HTTP preflight (OPTIONS) request fails in IE only

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, internet-explorer, cors

I trying to make a POST request to my REST API. Here is the code snippet (using AngularJS):

```
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: url,
            data: reqBody,
            headers: {
                'content-type': 'application/json'
            }
        })
        .then(function (response) {...})
        .catch(function (error) {...});
```

According to [this article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/), because of the HTTP header

> 'content-type': 'application/json'

browser concludes that it will have to make an "not-simple" HTTP request which requires handshake with a server (HTTP options request will be sent before actual HTTP request).

Chrome handles the request like a charm, but **IE (11 in my case) fails with the following messages**:

[image]

The thing is, HTTP options response contains everything the browser needs to proceed with the actual HTTP request.

Comment: Are the headers present in both the POST _and_ OPTIONS requests?

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv I really can't tell if the headers present in IE POST request, because it never get there. But, I checked Chrome POST headers and they are in place ([POST screenshot in Chrome](https://ibb.co/deJBK5)).

Comment: In my case I'm on IE11 (windows 10 home edition) and yes, all the OPTIONS request with an url "long" (concatenation of different kind of search params) fail. If I remove the search params (leaving getAll standard) the OPTIONS request (before the GET) works. So it's due to the length of URL? why? And how can I fix this stupid problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason for all that mess.

The API service and the website were located on the same domain, but on different ports. To be specific, the API service was located on:

> myDomain.com/apiService

and the website was located on:

> myDomain.com:44443/webSite

Thus, when the web browser was initializing the call from:

**myDomain.com:44443/webSite/page1**

to:

**myDomain.com/apiService/service1**

Internet Explorer was blocking the call because of the CORS. For some reason, Chrome was less strict in that matter, because it succeeded to make the call to the API.

To make it work in Internet Explorer, I moved the website to the same port as the API:

> myDomain.com/apiService
>
> myDomain.com/webSite

Answer (score 3):

You could add sites to Trusted zone in IE settings and set "Access data sources across domains" to Enable (not Prompt):

[image]

It works not only for IE 9, but 10+ as well.

More on this: https://www.webdavsystem.com/ajax/programming/cross_origin_requests

Comment: That solved the issue but I cannot tell to all my users to apply these changes into your browser :|