# IE 11 not passing Authorization header in API call

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, axios, cross-domain, internet-explorer-11

Stack : ReactJS, axios , api deployed on AWS

In My reactjs App, I am calling API deployed on aws using axios. This app is working perfectly in chrome and firefox, But failing in IE 11.

All apis are correctly configured to allow Authorization in access control header [image]

I am using below code to add authorization header and accessToken in a request

```
   const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: `https://abc.api.nonprod.org/`
});

export const createTokenHeaders = (idToken, accessToken) => ({
  authorization: `Bearer ${idToken}`,
  accessToken: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
});
// Add a request interceptor
export const reqInterceptor = config =>
  // get the bearer token and add it in the header
  Auth.currentSession()
    .then(data => {
      const idToken = data.getIdToken().getJwtToken();
      const accessToken = data.getAccessToken().getJwtToken();
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      config.headers = Object.assign({}, config.headers, createTokenHeaders(idToken, accessToken));
      return config;
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
      throw new Error('Error getting bearer token');
    });

axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(reqInterceptor);

export const performGet = (uri, queryParams = {}, headers) => {
  const requestParams = {
    params: queryParams,
    headers
  };
  return axiosInstance.get(uri, requestParams);
};
```

When I run this app in chrome from localhost:3000 then chrome is correctly calling OPTIONS request and then GET request with correct Authorization header.

But when I am running the same app in IE it is not calling OPTIONS request and also not passing Authorization header in GET request( however it is passing accessToken header).

Comment: Have you ever tried to use F12 developer tools to check whether it contains some error? Besides, with reference to [this thread](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1790), I suggest you could check whether you have added the web site to the IE's trusted site list. Try to remove from it. Besides, here is a [similar thread](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/891), you could check it.

Comment: Case-sensitivity, perhaps? See https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/10584749/ (this refers to Edge, but IE is mentioned to do the same type of comparison).

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792360/http-preflight-options-request-fails-in-ie-only

Answer (score 0):

Is you IE running on enhanced protection mode?
It does not seem to be code issue. 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-axios

react-native-axios support IE11.
use f12 debugger and check for not found url in network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to set `withCredentials: true` in order for authorization headers to be passed to CORS requests.