# How to fix request header content-type missing in IE11 | Angular 8 App

Tags: javascript, http, cors, internet-explorer-11

I am trying to update an Angular library to make it IE11 compliant.
The main problem that I'm facing is that all of the requests that the app makes to our backend fail in IE11. For chrome/firefox this issue is not present.

Here is what I see in the IE dev tools:

> `SEC7123: Request header content-type was not present in the Access-Control-Allow-Headers list.`
>   `SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network Error 0x80070005, Access is denied.`
>   `[object Object][object Object]`
>   `> message: "Http failure response for https://<redacted-url>/: 0 Unknown Error"`

**Is this a problem related to the server configuration or is there something I can change from the front-end?**

Please let me know if there is something else I can add to help find the issue.

PS: [Changing this internet explorer setting does solve the issue, but obviously it's not a viable solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45792360/http-preflight-options-request-fails-in-ie-only)

Also, I should note that the backend and the front-end are **NOT on the same domain**. (And this can't be changed)

Comment: it's a **server** issue - as the server sends that header

Comment: *For chrome/firefox this issue is not present.* - for some reason IE11 is sending a content-type header, but chrome/firefox are not - so perhaps it is a front end code doing some weird code crap for IE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed with a server-side change.
Apparently IE doesn't like the line:

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: '*'`

The headers must be explicited one by one.